# Is it possible to increase labels padding (NVD3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Labels on X Axis are to close to each other. They almost overlap. if you decrease chart width some labels disappear. Is it possible to make them disappear a bit earlier? I'm using `nv.models.lineChart` with custom scale:

```
var scale = d3.time.scale.utc();
chart.xScale(scale);
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263742/nvd3-configuring-ticks-on-axis).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you, but I don't get how it could help me. I just need to increase minimum margin(padding) between labels. When you shrink chart width NVD3 somehow decides that it's time to hide intermediate labels (because there is no room for them). But it decides to hide them when they almost overlap. It looks bad.

Comment: There's no minimum spacing between labels. The only thing you can affect is the labels themselves.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff But NVD3 determine number of x-ticks to show based on chart width, am I wrong? I need to alter this logic somehow.

Comment: No, it doesn't take the width of the chart into account.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff OK, but intermediate labels disappear if you shrink chart width. So, nubmer of labels somehow connected with chart width, in my opinion.

Comment: Ah ok, in the particular model that you're using it does affect it somewhat: `.ticks( availableWidth / 100 )`.